# Como mostrar comboboxes controles en Angular al seleccionar un checkbox

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Estoy iniciando con Angular y necesito convertir una aplicación de Silverlight a Angular, y se necesita que al momento de dar check a unos checkboxes me aparezcan unos selects o comboboxes.

Teniendo de referencia está [página](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-83jyvt) donde colocan como agregar o modificar controles (textboxes)

el codigo que creo que es adicionar select o comboboxes es el que indico:

```
  private addCheckboxes() {
this.orders.map((o, i) => {
  const control = new FormControl(i === 0); // if first item set to true, else false
  (this.form.controls.orders as FormArray).push(control);
});
```

}
pero como indico que son selects?

Comment: Hola ger. No te entiendo muy bien. Necesitas que aparezca el `select`? Puedes usar `*ngIf` para eso. Si pudieras explicarte un poco mas por favor para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @Angel si creo que debe haber un evento en commponent para que me dispare y le diga al html con *ngIf si esta chequeado colocar el combobox... el caso es que apenas estoy aprendiendo anglar... :( :'(

Comment: Ok. Déjame hago un pequeño ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con `[(ngModel)]`

En tu componente creas una variable:

```js
  mostrarSelect: boolean = false
```

Y en tu `html` agregas lo siguiente:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]='mostrarSelect' />Mostrar select

<hr>

<select *ngIf='mostrarSelect'>

  <option>Opciones</option>
  <option>Opciones</option>
  <option>Opciones</option>
  <option>Opciones</option>
</select>
```

Después puedes hacerlo progresivamente con un `*ngFor`.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmedye)